# Mysql Select Query With No loop

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table - 1
---------------------
 ID  | Name | Value |
---------------------
---------------------
 1   |   a  |  aa   |
---------------------
---------------------
 2   |   b  |  bb   |
---------------------
---------------------
 3   |   c  |  cc   |
---------------------

Table - 2
---------------------
 ID  | Name | Value |
---------------------
---------------------
 1   |   x  |  xx   |
---------------------
---------------------
 3   |   y  |  yy   |
---------------------
---------------------
 4   |   z  |  zz   |
---------------------
```

---

```
Output
=================

a | x

a | y

a | z

b | x

b | y

b | z

c | x

c | y

c | z
```

I want this output with these two tables with mysql query,no loop,only mysql statements.

Comment: What are the names of your tables? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `CROSS JOIN` to get the Results.

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Name, B.Name
FROM Table_1 A
CROSS JOIN Table_2 B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cartesian Join or Cross Join`.

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table2.Name FROM Table1, Table2;
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query :-

```
SELECT t1.name, t2.name
FROM t2
CROSS JOIN t1
```

Output :-

a | x

a | y

a | z

b | x

b | y

b | z

c | x

c | y

c | z